# Search record in form Google sheet

Tags: google-apps-script

I created a form and tried to search for records but with no success
[This is my sheet link][1]
[1]: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1FyM3xaDE6LhdHSxwIBrw-NAx1Mcn_Dezzgi_JWJtDWU/edit?usp=sharing

```
 var SEARCH_COL_IDX=0;
 function Search(){

var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var formS = ss.getSheetByName('フォーム');
//var data = ss.getSheetByName('データ管理');

var str= formS.getRange("M3").getValue();
var values= ss.getSheetByName("データ管理").getDataRange().getValues();
for(var i=0;i<values.length;i++){
  var row= values[i];
  if(row[SEARCH_COL_IDX] == str){
    
             formS.getRange("D3").setValue(row[0]);//title
             formS.getRange("D7").setValue(row[1]);//ID
             formS.getRange("D9").setValue(row[2]);//daytime
             formS.getRange("I9").setValue(row[3]);//Check data
             formS.getRange("D13").setValue(row[4]);//input1
             formS.getRange("D21").setValue(row[5]);//input2
             formS.getRange("D30").setValue(row[6]);//input3
             formS.getRange("D39").setValue(row[7]);//input4
             formS.getRange("C50").setValue(row[8]);//Implementation date
             formS.getRange("C55").setValue(row[9]);//Date of enactment
             formS.getRange("J50").setValue(row[10]);//管理者
             formS.getRange("J55").setValue(row[11]);//制定者
    
   
  }
}
}
```

Comment: Please provide [mcve] and data to test width.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is basically the same thing and it works:

```
function testfunc() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh2 = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet2');
  var str = sh2.getRange('A1').getValue();//get search value for col1
  var vs = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1').getDataRange().getValues();
  vs.forEach(r => {
    if (r[0] == str) {
      sh2.appendRow(r);//I appended the row because it's easier
    }
  });
}
```

My Sheet1:

| COL1 | COL2 | COL3 | COL4 | COL5 | COL6 | COL7 | COL8 | COL9 | COL10 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 6 | 12 | 4 | 21 | 6 | 19 | 23 | 20 | 2 | 18 |
| 12 | 4 | 15 | 1 | 25 | 15 | 7 | 14 | 15 | 2 |
| 18 | 16 | 22 | 10 | 19 | 19 | 3 | 20 | 29 | 12 |
| 24 | 28 | 7 | 13 | 12 | 11 | 27 | 26 | 11 | 4 |
| 0 | 28 | 6 | 0 | 14 | 2 | 23 | 25 | 23 | 28 |
| 5 | 23 | 7 | 16 | 6 | 29 | 9 | 9 | 12 | 22 |
| 23 | 15 | 5 | 7 | 7 | 14 | 17 | 9 | 10 | 0 |
| 4 | 1 | 0 | 25 | 16 | 2 | 19 | 24 | 20 | 12 |
| 19 | 8 | 3 | 2 | 20 | 22 | 28 | 14 | 8 | 15 |
| 16 | 6 | 23 | 24 | 18 | 17 | 20 | 2 | 13 | 12 |
| 24 | 5 | 23 | 29 | 19 | 17 | 23 | 10 | 22 | 12 |
| 8 | 11 | 25 | 6 | 15 | 2 | 7 | 14 | 10 | 17 |
| 21 | 29 | 4 | 25 | 9 | 27 | 0 | 15 | 29 | 19 |
| 4 | 28 | 16 | 15 | 4 | 19 | 16 | 7 | 6 | 15 |
| 19 | 17 | 0 | 5 | 23 | 11 | 26 | 18 | 16 | 2 |
| 14 | 2 | 7 | 6 | 16 | 21 | 18 | 26 | 29 | 1 |
| 17 | 8 | 29 | 1 | 1 | 15 | 11 | 12 | 24 | 20 |
| 22 | 19 | 6 | 13 | 1 | 6 | 6 | 29 | 5 | 26 |
| 17 | 7 | 24 | 1 | 18 | 7 | 21 | 20 | 26 | 29 |
| 16 | 28 | 9 | 12 | 21 | 16 | 7 | 5 | 8 | 9 |
| 5 | 7 | 27 | 23 | 12 | 9 | 19 | 18 | 20 | 26 |
| 22 | 15 | 23 | 4 | 27 | 29 | 16 | 15 | 22 | 17 |
| 25 | 7 | 19 | 15 | 17 | 18 | 24 | 25 | 7 | 2 |
| 7 | 18 | 14 | 1 | 10 | 23 | 14 | 1 | 29 | 3 |
| 11 | 5 | 22 | 9 | 0 | 26 | 4 | 23 | 23 | 4 |
| 10 | 12 | 16 | 19 | 28 | 6 | 25 | 0 | 0 | 14 |
| 24 | 9 | 18 | 9 | 29 | 19 | 8 | 8 | 11 | 22 |
| 20 | 29 | 23 | 15 | 0 | 27 | 14 | 19 | 2 | 22 |
| 18 | 18 | 2 | 22 | 24 | 7 | 26 | 20 | 11 | 23 |
| 15 | 7 | 17 | 15 | 12 | 6 | 15 | 24 | 8 | 21 |

My Sheet2:

| 22 | Search Value |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 22 | 19 | 6 | 13 | 1 | 6 | 6 | 29 | 5 | 26 |
| 22 | 15 | 23 | 4 | 27 | 29 | 16 | 15 | 22 | 17 |